# Pushing down the body and background universally

Tags: html, css, margin

So, there have been some questions about this already, but mine is a bit more specific.

I want to add a 40px high admin bar to the top of all pages of my CMS when the user is logged in as an admin.

But I don't want to obscure the content on the page, so I want to push it down. Remember, this is a CMS so there is a lot of different CSS/designs on all the pages that use it. The system do have control of all the CSS though, so I can change it on the fly.

I started out by adding a "margin-top: 40px" to the body element before realizing that the background-image of BODY isn't actually attached to the body, but rather the otherwise unstylable root element.

So, I used "background-position: 0 40px" to move down the background image. Score! Only, some sites already used background-position to position their background in relation to the content and me overriding that severely messed up the design of those pages.

So - is there a better way to handle this? Or am I going to have to parse and alter every sites possible background-position on the fly - which I *can* do, but rather not :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem, you could change the way your CMS functions. Add a full page wrapper `div` that acts as a body for the user's content. Then, inserting a 40px high element above the wrapper will universally push it down.

Comment: The problem isn't pushing the content down, that's easy. But I need the *background image* to also be pushed down, which is where my problem is.

Comment: If the background image is applied to that div wrapper (rather than the actual body), it will be pushed down consistently.

Comment: I'm note sure said DIV could be made to be as high as the viewport in all instances though... This may be a potential source for new layout problems...

Comment: @Sandman how would that push down the BODY background image..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, you might need to position your cms toolbar negatively though.

```
html { margin-top: 40px; }
#yourCmsBar { position: absolute; top: -40px; height: 40px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push down the html element if the background is applied to the html element, and then use `position:absolute` to positioning your header. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u22zE/2/

Comment: Yes, but that won't push down the background image of the BODY tag.

Comment: @Sandman That should push down even the background image is applied in the body tag, because the body tag is into the html tag. See my example in the post, I fixed a bug in Firefox

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. Use the DOM inspector to hide the header tag and you'll see the background image beneath it. The background image isn't actually attached to the body DOM object, but to the root object and as such, won't be affected by any margins set to the body tag.

Comment: @Sandman I see, the background image still back of the header, but the background image is already moved. If you add `repeat-x` to the html background you are going to see background moved. Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/u22zE/4/